# .dotnet core container set up in NGINX Unit

Tags: docker, podman, nginx-upstreams, nginx-unit, docker.dotnet

I have created podman image with my .net core application. I run it on Debian 12 and it works fine. The container is an addon to Go Lang application. Issue of podman is that it doesnt restart container, after server restart.
All the applications are running on NGINX Unit. And here comes my question: How can I manage my container using nginx unit? Is it the right way to use this tool?

I wanted to run it as an upstream confguration something like:

```
    "listeners": {
        "*:80": {
            "pass": "upstreams/my-container"
        }
    },

    "upstreams": {
        "my-container": {
            "servers": {
                "127.0.0.1:8080": {},
            }
        }
    }
```

But can I manage restarting podman etc? or maybe there is other way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

We have re-checked documentation, we will use serviced to manage the podman service, and the Nginx unit to manage our applications. Unfortunately Nginx unit doesnt provide a way to manage external application.